# How to add a toast in SwipeMenuListView to the "open" item?

Tags: android, onclick, toast, android-toast

I've ran the sample of baoyz' library and everything worked perfectly. Now I didn't much get all the code into my head about it. In the "Simple Activity" class, the menu is located. (For more info, look at the repo here: https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView )
Now I want to set a toast for it when I click "open". By default, when I click open, nothing happens. What I want it to do is display a message "Worked" just so I can know and get the next step of building.
SimpleActivity.java:
package com.baoyz.swipemenulistviewsample;

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenu;
import com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuCreator;
import com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuItem;
import com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuLayout;
import com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView;
import com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView.OnMenuItemClickListener;
import com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView.OnSwipeListener;

public class SimpleActivity extends Activity {

    private List<ApplicationInfo> mAppList;
    private AppAdapter mAdapter;
    private SwipeMenuListView mListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        mAppList = getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(0);

        mListView = (SwipeMenuListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mAdapter = new AppAdapter();
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // step 1. create a MenuCreator
        SwipeMenuCreator creator = new SwipeMenuCreator() {

            @Override
            public void create(SwipeMenu menu) {
                // create "open" item
                SwipeMenuItem openItem = new SwipeMenuItem(
                        getApplicationContext());
                // set item background
                openItem.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0xC9, 0xC9,
                        0xCE)));
                // set item width
                openItem.setWidth(dp2px(90));
                // set item title
                openItem.setTitle("Open");
                // set item title fontsize
                openItem.setTitleSize(18);
                // set item title font color
                openItem.setTitleColor(Color.WHITE);
                // add to menu
                menu.addMenuItem(openItem);

                // create "delete" item
                SwipeMenuItem deleteItem = new SwipeMenuItem(
                        getApplicationContext());
                // set item background
                deleteItem.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0xF9,
                        0x3F, 0x25)));
                // set item width
                deleteItem.setWidth(dp2px(90));
                // set a icon
                deleteItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_delete);
                // add to menu
                menu.addMenuItem(deleteItem);

            }
        };
        // set creator
        mListView.setMenuCreator(creator);

        // step 2. listener item click event
        mListView.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(int position, SwipeMenu menu, int index) {
                ApplicationInfo item = mAppList.get(position);
                switch (index) {
                case 0:
                    // open
                    open(item);
                    break;
                    mAppList.
                case 1:
                    // delete
//                  delete(item);
                    mAppList.remove(position);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        // set SwipeListener
        mListView.setOnSwipeListener(new OnSwipeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSwipeStart(int position) {
                // swipe start
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwipeEnd(int position) {
                // swipe end
            }
        });

        // other setting
//      listView.setCloseInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());

        // test item long click
        mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), position + " long click", 0).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    private void delete(ApplicationInfo item) {
        // delete app
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
            intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("package", item.packageName, null));
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    private void open(ApplicationInfo item) {
        // open app
        Intent resolveIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        resolveIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        resolveIntent.setPackage(item.packageName);
        List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = getPackageManager()
                .queryIntentActivities(resolveIntent, 0);
        if (resolveInfoList != null && resolveInfoList.size() > 0) {
            ResolveInfo resolveInfo = resolveInfoList.get(0);
            String activityPackageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            String className = resolveInfo.activityInfo.name;

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(
                    activityPackageName, className);

            intent.setComponent(componentName);
            startActivity(intent);


            )
        }
    }

    class AppAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mAppList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public ApplicationInfo getItem(int position) {
            return mAppList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.layout.item_list_app, null);
                new ViewHolder(convertView);
            }
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            ApplicationInfo item = getItem(position);
            holder.iv_icon.setImageDrawable(item.loadIcon(getPackageManager()));
            holder.tv_name.setText(item.loadLabel(getPackageManager()));
            return convertView;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            ImageView iv_icon;
            TextView tv_name;

            public ViewHolder(View view) {
                iv_icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon);
                tv_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
                view.setTag(this);
            }
        }
    }

    private int dp2px(int dp) {
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp,
                getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

}
```

I haven't done anything to it yet, I just want to know where to implement the toast action. 
Thanks

Comment: Would that only be for debugging? Why not use logcat then?

Answer (score -1):

Set an `OnClickListener` for `openItem`:

```
openItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

As a comment said, use logcat for debugging if you are not implementing an action onClick just yet.